# have been vs. are

Tags: grammar

1. The minister's are expected to answer people's question tomorrow.
2. The minister's have been expected to answer people's question tomorrow.

Are both grammatical?
Or is it that 2. is not correct because we've used "tomorrow" in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical, but no. 2 is very unlikely to occur.

I can only imagine it in a context like

> Up to now, the ministers have been expected to answer people's questions tomorrow. But we have been told to expect an announcement that [something different is going to happen].

So the context established that the expectation is in the recent past, continuing up to the present, even though the expectation concerns events in the future.

If the change of plan were in the past, even in the immediate past, I would expect a past perfect for the expectation:

> Up to ten minutes ago, the ministers had been expected to answer  the people's questions tomorrow, but the Prime Minister has just announced that ...

In either case, I think that "it has/had been expected that the ministers would answer people's questions tomorrow" is more likely, but the forms I have given are possible.

[Note: I have corrected two probably errors in your examples: "minister's" is possessive, "ministers" is plural; and "people's question", without an article, is very unlikely.]