# Present continuous vs. present perfect continuous usage in context

Tags: grammar, tense

I would like to understand the distinction in meaning between the two sentences, and the context that perhaps may require (or better fit) the present continuous or the present perfect continuous.

> 1: John *is exercising* at least twice a week.

> 2: John *has been exercising* at least twice a week.

Intuitively, the present perfect continuous seems to suggest that a change has occurred relatively recently which led John to this exercise regimen. There is no suggestion of change (past or future) when using the present continuous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [have been vs. are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161768/have-been-vs-are)

Comment: Yes, #2 *tends* to imply John only *started* this exercise regime relatively recently (and/or that he might not *continue* into the future). But don't overapply that perspective, because #1 is a relatively uncommon format - if we wanted to get right away from that implication of "change", we'd use Simple Present: *John **exercises** at least twice a week*.

Comment: according to perfect-english-grammar.com both  sentences are used for a new and/or temporary habits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your reply is helpful, thank you! It brings up another  question. What might be the context in which the present continuous would be appropriate or recommended?

Comment: You *might* use present continuous as per your example #1 if John's exercise regime started relatively recently (as per present perfect example #2), but his *future* exercise is contextually more important than the *recent past* exercise. That's because present continuous here strongly implies the recent exercise affects his *current* state (he's toned, and in good condition). Present continuous doesn't carry *that* implication, but it *can* imply ***...and will continue exercising** [in order to achieve some particular goal in the relatively near **future**, perhaps]*.

Comment: *I work here one day a week* (have done for a long time, expect to continue indefinitely). *I am working here one day a week* (started not long ago, no plans to quit, but maybe less "long-term" than Simple Present). *I have been working here one day a week* (started not long ago, possibly planning to quit soon).

Comment: Me: I usually go to the gym on the High Street, but it's closed for repairs at the moment so I've been going(1)/ am going (2) to the one in the shopping centre. How about you?_____Which one is correct to use here (1) or (2)?